# div with flex display spacing between inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use Flex to have a div that has inputs and I wanted it to occupy the entire center of the screen with space between the inputs without needing to use margin bottom to have space between them, I thought this code was enough, but they There is no space between them. Is it possible to do this with CSS without using margin-bottom in the inputs?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-1 {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.bg-gray-700 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(28 28 28 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

```html
<div class="flex flex-1 flex-col space-between">
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <div class="flex items-center">
        banner
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 justify-center space-between bg-gray-700">
    <div class="flex flex-col space-between">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex justify-center">
      <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

basically I wanted to have spacing between the inputs and the button and the header.

Comment: `space-between` requires that there IS space available. If the height of the parent is only the height of the contents there is no available space.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: Give the parent a height, greater than the sum of the contents, or use `margin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create space between input elements, you can use the .gap-2 class. It adds a gap between the input elements. Here's an example of how it works:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-1 {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.bg-gray-700 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(28 28 28 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.p-3 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.gap-2 {
    gap: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex flex-1 flex-col space-between gap-2">
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <div class="flex items-center">
        banner
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 justify-center space-between bg-gray-700 p-3">
    <div class="flex flex-col space-between gap-2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex justify-center">
      <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```